# SecurityException is not forwarded from service to its manager

Tags: java, android, exception

I have a service which has external APIs.
In some cases I have to throw SecurityException.
The strange thing is the following:
In some APIs when I throw the exception, the binder successfully makes this transaction 
and the exception is caught by the service's manager.
However, in other APIs the exception does not reach the manager, because the Binder swallows 
it. 
The Binder log message is as follows:
**"06-Nov 06:04:05.766  3632    W   Binder  Binder call failed."**
As it is seen from the Binder code, the exception is swallowed , since the transaction is ONE WAY:

```
           if ((flags & FLAG_ONEWAY) != 0) {
737                if (e instanceof RemoteException) {
738                    Log.w(TAG, "Binder call failed.", e);
739                } else {
740                    Log.w(TAG, "Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.", e);
741                }
742            } else {
743                // Clear the parcel before writing the exception
744                reply.setDataSize(0);
745                reply.setDataPosition(0);
746                reply.writeException(e);
747            }
```

I need the exception be forwarded. I don't understand why in some cases the exception is forwarded and in other - not. I don't see any differences between the two types of APIs.  How can I cause my exception be not ONE WAY, if it is possible?
Please help.
Thanks in advance.
Regards , Sveta

Answer (score 0):

I'found an answer to my question. The problem occurred because the "problematic" APIs are defined as oneway in the AIDL. So they are asynchronous. That's why it was a mistake to send an Exception from within those API, because in oneway APIs the link to the app process (in context of which manager runs) is lost.